# safari Version 10.0.3 (12602.4.8) and Os 10.12.3 hotmail will not allow login

Tags: safari

since an up date safari Version 10.0.3 (12602.4.8) and Os 10.12.3 hotmail will not allow login due password fail or allow password reset however it works fine in Firefox and thunderbird .. on the same imac so the fault is 100% safari any ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

found the problem java was not updated I needed to uninstall java then install the latest version it all works fine !!!!

more info :-

https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_java_update.xml